# Mapping (key, value) (key, value) to (key, (value1, value2)) in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of tuples of the form (User, Page):

```
tuples = [(Tim, PageFoo), (Jen,PageBar), (Tim, PageBaz), ...]
```

I want to loop over this list and create a new list or dict of pages per user:

```
newlist = [(Tim,[PageFoo, PageBaz]), (Jen, [PageBar]), ...]
```

The problem I'm having is that these pages aren't in order by user - as I loop, I need to check newlist to see if the User already exists, and if so, update the list.

Can anyone help me get through my mental block?

Comment: This is what `dict`s (and `defaultdict`s) are made to do.

Comment: So if I have a dict {'Tim': [Foo, Baz], 'Jen':[Bar]}, how can I pull the values that correspond with Tim and add to that list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Aशwini चhaudhary was faster, but here is `defaultdict` solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tuples = [('Tim', 'PageFoo'), ('Jen','PageBar'), ('Tim', 'PageBaz')]
result = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in tuples:
    result[key].append(value)
result
# Out[8]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Tim': ['PageFoo', 'PageBaz'], 'Jen': ['PageBar']})
dict(result)
# Out[9]: {'Jen': ['PageBar'], 'Tim': ['PageFoo', 'PageBaz']} 
result.items()
# Out[10]: [('Tim', ['PageFoo', 'PageBaz']), ('Jen', ['PageBar'])]
```

Comment: Unless the original order is necessary, this is the better solution.  It's what `defaultdict` was made for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for this, if order doesn't matter then go for [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
tuples = [('Tim', 'PageFoo'), ('Jen', 'PageBar'), ('Tim', 'PageBaz')]
d = OrderedDict()
for k, v in tuples:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

>>> d.items()
[('Tim', ['PageFoo', 'PageBaz']), ('Jen', ['PageBar'])]
```

Comment: @That1Guy There's no need to use `setdefault` in defaultdict. defaultdict will automatically set the value of missing key.

Comment: you cannot use `defaultdict` if you want to preserve order. You need `OrderedDict`, hence you need `defaultdict.setdefault` or `dict.get(key, default=[])` here.

Comment: @m.wasowski: The OP didn't say he needed to preserve order, but that the lack of order was making it difficult for him.